# Homogeneous binary quartic forms to elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups

- Broadly I would like to know what is the connection between homogeneous binary quartic forms and elliptic curves.

  I see that the invariants on the first space under the action of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ are precisely the functions $g_2$ and $g_3$. Also given such a quartic form on $\mathbb{C}^2$, if one thinks its 0-set as the intersection of two conics in $\mathbb{C}^3$ then the determinant of the complex symmetric matrix representing the most general conic passing through this intersection is precisely the "RHS" of the elliptic curve equation.
- What does this determinant mean geometrically?

More specifically consider the $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ action on $\mathbb{C}^2$ (spanned by $x$ and $y$) and define $U = x^2$, $V = 2xy$ and $W=y^2$.

If the action is by the matrix $ \left [ \begin{array}{c  c } 
                                     a & b \\
                                     c & d \\
                                                                 
                           
   \end{array}\right ]$ ($ad-bc=1$) of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ then the following transformation is affected on $\mathbb{C}^2$,

$$ \left [  \begin{array}{c} 
                            x\\
                            y\\
                                                                 
                          
   \end{array} \right ]  \rightarrow \left [  \begin{array}{c} 
                            ax + by\\
                            cx + dy\\
                                                                 
                           
   \end{array} \right ] $$

This in turn implies the following transformation on $\mathbb{C}^3$ (defining the matrices, $X$ and $A$),

$$X = \left [  \begin{array}{c} 
                            U\\
                            V\\
                            W
                                                                 
                          
   \end{array} \right ]  \rightarrow  A.X  = \left [  \begin{array}{c c c} 
                            a^2 & ab & b^2\\
                            2ac & (ad+bc) & 2bd \\
                            c^2 & cd & d^2\\
                                                                 
                           
   \end{array} \right ] \left [  \begin{array}{c} 
                            U\\
                            V\\
                            W
                                                                 
                          
   \end{array} \right ] $$

$4UW-V^2$ being identically equal to $0$ is obviously kept invariant by the above transformation.

The invariance of $4UW-V^2$ can be thought of as $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ preserving an inner-product on $\mathbb{C}^3$ with signature, $\left [ \begin{array}{c c c} 
                                     &   & 2 \\
                                     & -1 &  \\
                                     2 & &  \\
                              
                           
   \end{array} \right ]$

- But $A$ does not seem to be an orthogonal matrix though it satisfies the property of $det(A)=1$. Then why is it being said in the books that the $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ action on $\mathbb{C}^2$ (spanned by $x$ and $y$) induces an action of $SO(3)$ on $\mathbb{C}^3$ (spanned by $U$, $V$ and $W$) with respect to the inner product $ \left [ \begin{array}{c  c c}  
                                       &   & 2 \\
                                       & -1 &  \\
                                       2 & &  \\
                                
                             
     \end{array}\right ]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It *is* orthogonal with respect to the given inner product:

> sage: R.<a,b,c,d> = QQ['a,b,c,d']
>   sage: R2 = R.quotient_ring(a*d-b*c-1)
>   sage: A = Matrix(R2,[[a^2,a*b,b^2],[2*a*c, a*d+b*c, 2*b*d],[c^2,c*d,d^2]])
>   sage: J = Matrix([[0,0,2],[0,-1,0],[2,0,0]])
>   sage: A.transpose()*J*A == J
>   True

Comment: I didn't understand that code you wrote. By a matrix being in $SO(3)$ I would think that it is a $3\times 3$ matrix which satisfies the equation $A^{T}A=AA^{T}=I$.

Comment: @Anirbit: That's orthogonal with respect to the standard quadratic form. There is an orthogonal group associated with any quadratic form: if the form is given by $x^tJy$, then the orthogonal matrices are those that satisfy $A^tJA=J$.

Comment: But in that case will $A$ be an element of $SO(3)$? If you change the quadratic form then shouldn't the Lie group also change?